# How do I get from the power series $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(z-c)^n$ to a polynomial?

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials

We are supposed to show that if $f^{(n)}(z)=0$ for all $z\in G$ then f is a polynomial of maximal degree $n-1$.

My approach is to use Cauchy's differentiation formula. We know $f$ can be expressed as a power series for $c\in G$ and some open disc $D$ around $c$ in $G$ as follows:
$$f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n(z-c)^n, \quad z\in D$$
Now using $f^{(n)}(z)=0$ it is easy to show that all $a_{k\geq n}=0$, which is close to what we want to show. How do I generalize from the power series which converges on $D$ around $c$ to state that the function is actually a polynomial? Do we even know that $c=0 \in G$? At $0$ the power series would look like a polynomial...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A polynomial is a polynomial regardless of how it's written, e.g. $(z-c)^n$ *is* a polynomial.